# Docker cannot add file in sub directory

Tags: docker

I run the docker file as below logic:

```
FROM hub.docker.prod.abc.com/library/ubuntu:bionic

...

# Set up working directory
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

...

# Copy files
ADD server.py /app
ADD test.py /app
ADD sub/evaluate.py /app
```

The docker build failed when 'ADD sub/evaluate.py /app'. I also try to use 'COPY' to replace 'ADD', but got the same error. Does this mean I can not add file in the sub directory? server.py,test.py, and sub/evaluate.py are files from my local environment. Please help and thanks.

Comment: try this COPY ["server.py", "/app"]

Comment: thanks. Should I try COPY["server.py", "/app"] or  COPY["sub/evaluate.py", "/app"]  since it failed in line ADD sub/evaluate.py /app.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: 16:57:02 Step 27/55 : ADD test.py /app
16:57:02 Build done. However, ADD sub/evaluate.py /app is not executed.